# Fiddler with White UI automation

Tags: wpf, fiddler, ui-automation, white-framework

I have very wired problem.

I have a WPF application that calls web services.

When I run the application I can see the communication to the services through fiddler.

I wrote some UI automation test for the WPF application, using White framework from thoughtworks.

When I run the tests with NUnit, the tests will start up the application, but I cannot see the communication to the web services through fiddler

anybody has idea?

Comment: You asked this question here: http://groups.google.com/group/httpfiddler/browse_thread/thread/938027110dc351b3

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that fiddler and your test are running as the same user account.  I have had this problem when the automated test is logging in as a different account than myself.  You just need to do a run-as with fiddler.